# windows user domain account question

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have one question regarding domain account. I have one domain controller where all the user information are stored. I have joined the domain on my laptop but I observed that I am able to log-in using domain credentials even if domain controller is down. How is this possible?

Kind Regards 
PK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've logged on to the laptop prior to the Domain Controller being down, your credentials are cached locally on the machine.

This occurs so that you can use your domain credentials to log into the machine even if you are disconnected from the network (working from home, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

You're using cached credentials. You can disable this in the registry if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will cache previous user login credentials locally so you can still log in if the DC is down. You shouldn't be able to access network resources that might need you to login though.